# how to loop through posts in both front page and blog page?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display some posts in home page according to post type but i can't access posts and post loop returns " Home " post only ,so what is the proper way to make this happen ?

my reading settings

- Front page displays : A static page
- Front page :home
- Posts page :blogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your reading settings the way they are.

You can create a theme file called `front-page.php` and use this to control your home page.

Within your `front-page.php` you can use [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to retrieve posts and then loop through them

Example:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10, // number of posts to return
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type' // change this to the post type you want to retrieve
);


$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) : 
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>


    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @HatemTito You're welcome. You can use `numberposts` and `posts_per_page` interchangeably.